# Android notifications - wrong notification intent received

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a very strange situation with notifications (Android, Java).

I have created 3 different notifications (by this code):

```
    int id = getWeekNotificationId(notification);// different id than 25
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderNotifications.class);
    ...set intent data
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context, id, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
      alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, pendingIntent);
    } else {
      alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, pendingIntent);
    }
```

[image]

Then I created notification with id 25 (it's different part of code):

```
 public void scheduleNotification(int id, Context context) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationPublisher.class);
    ...set intent data
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context, id, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 0, pendingIntent);
  }
```

[image]

then I cancel this last notification (with id 25):

```
   NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancel(25)
```

And it's correctly not showing in the bar.

[image]

And here is my problem:

- after clicking on any of these three notifications the notification with id 25 is received (the intent data corresponds to this notification). ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

What I'm missing? Correct id assignment or anything else?

Comment: You used `id` for `requestCode`. The position you used `id` is `requestCode` parameter. you can flag by requestCode but It's not `notification id`. You may used same *real* notification Id in `notificationManager.notify(Id, notification)` with others.

Comment: I'm definitely doing something wrong with setup/cancel notification by id ... do you have any example of correct setup? Thanks

Comment: [notify](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)), [cancel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#cancel(int)) this is all for you. If it is not enough, Could you post your setup, notify and cancel(detect) code?

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I was missing, I will try it ASAP